# Gensim 4.0.0 get the word having key in model.wv

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

```
with open(args.output, 'w+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write('%d %d\n' % (len(model.wv), args.size))
    for key in tqdm(model.wv): 
        // code //
        f.write(WORD, VECTOR)
```

I want to create a txt file that contains the Word and the embedding vector.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean - can you edit your question to be clearer?

In normal `Word2Vec` usage, the `wv` object is an instance of `KeyedVectors`, and the words themselves are the keys. You can perform indexed-access (Python brackets `wv[…]`) using word-strings to get the associated vector.

If you want a list of all keys, you can either:

- look at the list of keys, in the same order as backing rows in the underlying array, in `model.wv.index_to_key`
- get all the keys in the `dict` that maps keys to index positions: `model.wv.key_to_index.keys()`

It almost looks like you're trying to write the vectors to a simple text format. You may want to use the `.save_word2vec_format()` method instead:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.KeyedVectors.save_word2vec_format